# Any suggestion on how to read Symfony2 source code?

Tags: symfony

I'm interesting reading Symfony2 source code and want to figure out how everything works.

Where should I start? From the `app_dev.php` and then open the files read line by line?

Or are there some big pictures or key points of the base code design? I have almost read all of the documents from symfony.com.

Comment: You can start by [HttpKernel::handleRaw](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/HttpKernel.php#L94)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before diving into Symfony2 source code, I would suggest starting with [Create your own framework... on top of the Symfony2 Components](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1) serie of [12 articles](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1). It explains well the role of each component and the way they can be used.

Comment: Create your own framework... on top of the Symfony2 Components is the best place to start with

Comment: Absolutely.  But consider using this link instead: https://github.com/fabpot/Create-Your-Framework  It's updated to S2.3 and will perhaps avoid some confusion, especially about autoloading via composer instead of using the symfony universal class loader.

Comment: That's a great post to start.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony2 was documented in such a way to help people who are in the exact place you're in. They have a few specific docs that I think will help.

---

## The Quick Tour

[Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html)

Sections:

1. [The Big Picture](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html)
2. [The View](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_view.html)
3. [The Controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_controller.html)
4. [The Architecture](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html)

> This chapter will walk you through some of the most important concepts behind Symfony2 and explain how you can get started quickly by showing you a simple project in action.

Basically, this Tour provides a quick way for you to learn the essentials. The last part of the tour, [The Architecture](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html), is an awesome resource. It will help you understand how Symfony2 is built with emphasis on bundles and  the directory structure of Symfony2.

Now let's move on to the more advanced stuff.

## Internals

[Source](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html)

> Looks like you want to understand how Symfony2 works and how to extend it. This section is an in-depth explanation of the Symfony2 internals.

The Symfony 2 docs has a specific section for you to learn about the inner workings of Symfony. The main focus is on the [kernel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel) which is truly important to grasp if you want to master Symfony2.

Once you read through this, I would suggest that you think of some things that you can do just in the kernel (without the help of vendor code) and play around in the kernel. This is really the best way to learn.

Once you grasp the kernel, then focus on the components. [This](http://symfony.com/components) is a great doc for quickly getting to any specific Component documentation.

My last suggestion would be to attend conferences and meet ups, if you're able. If you're interested, visit [live.symfony.com](http://live.symfony.com/). They post upcoming conferences and their speakers, schedules, etc. You'll be blown away at how much you can learn at a conference.

Comment: Very appreciate your suggestions.